# Do you have to install Git separately from GitHub for Mac?

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I am a novice coder and I write a blog about learning to program aimed at journalists.

Learning the basics of how to use a version control system was one of the best things I learned this year, and I am now writing a tutorial about it.

Here is my question:

Do you have to install Git separately from Github's graphical client, GitHub for Mac?  If it's possible to avoid command-line operations, I may choose to write the tutorial just focusing on downloading and installing GitHub for Mac and walking the user through the process of making new repos, forking, rolling back, etc.

Comment: You now can install git with "GitHub for Mac": see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want to do any git stuff on the command line, you'll need to install it. You'll especially want to do it because Github for Mac doesn't let you do everything you need to out of the box. For example you can't do a push without commit *everything* which can be annoying if you need to push a feature quickly without branching. Also, it is good for learnings!

You'll find an easy shortcut to install it under the "Github" menu: "Install Command Line Utility..."

[image]

Comment: Cool, I notice you're new, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (tick under voting)  :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I did it :)

Comment: @Dunhamzzz That menu item only seems to put an alias in the /usr/local/bin folder

Comment: as Jon pointed out, the install command line utility menu item DOES NOT install git itself, it simply create an alias to the GitHub app so that it's available in the command line ...

Comment: @Dunhamzzz I don't feel this has answered the question. It seems that you cannot use git commands by clicking the GitHub for Mac's 'install command line utility'. It seems a little strange to offer the functionality of simply launching the GUI from the command line. Can you elaborate on what exactly it is you can do with the command line utility that goes beyond launching the GitHub for Mac's application?

Comment: @shennan The Github GUI is just a basic interface for committing/pushing/pulling. From the command line you have a plethora of tools such as rebase, bisect, stash etc.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz I'm aware of that. You're missing my point. I think it's reasonable to assume that the GUI would run on top of a genuine version of git, where you can interact with some of its other features through the command line. This doesn't seem to be the case. When was the last time you downloaded GitHub for Mac and were able to do anything other than launch it's application from the command line with the github command. All the 'install command line utility' seems to do is put an alias to the GitHub app in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You now can, (May 2013) install git directly from "[GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/)"

See the blog "[Installing Git from GitHub for Mac](https://github.com/blog/1510-installing-git-from-github-for-mac)", you can install only the GUI, or the GUI *and* a regular git CLI (Command-Line Interface)

> you can now easily install Git for use on the command line, without needing to download any separate packages.

When there is a new release of git, you don't have to do anything:

> And whenever we update the version of Git included with GitHub for Mac, you'll get the changes automatically – no work required on your part!

There is a new "Advanced" option:

> you may notice some changes to the Preferences window.
>   On the newly renamed "`Advanced`" tab, simply click "`Install Command Line Tools`".

[image: click install]

> You'll be prompted for an administrator password so that Git can be installed into `/usr/local/bin`, and then you should very shortly see that it succeeded:

[image]